# Can activity diagram stards with decision node?

Tags: uml, diagram, diagramming

I'm modelling an activity and the flow is very different from the beginnin - either user receives a message (when logged in) or receives an email (and later logs in).
I somehow remember that before diamond there must be an activity, or can I do it like this?

```
>           O
>  [email]  |   [internal message received]
>         --<>---
```

Mind you I must stick to correct UML notation/syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The diamond is a graphical representation used by Decision and Merge activity nodes and several rules exist according to your context (decision, merge or both).
These rules mainly deal with the number or the type of incoming or outgoing flows but the source of flow can not be an activity, it shall be an activity node.

Hoping it helps,

RB

Comment: THank you but what should I put there if there is no activity? The acitivy begins just when the user clicks on the link or internal message :(

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more what you want to model, it would be useful for my understanding.

Comment: E.g an invitation can be send via private mesasge in the system OR via an email. Both will go the same way then, but when an email was sent, the user has to login at first.